# How to get full display name for locale

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show "繁體中文", "简体中文" in a view.

I use Locale.displayname to get displayname and my parameter is "zh-Hant" and "zh-Hans", the value will return "中文（繁體）"and "中文（简体）".

Here is parts of my code:

```
let loacleName = locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: "zh-Hant")
```

Is anyone know how can I get "繁體中文", "简体中文" from iOS function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution using native `Locale`. For the identifiers `zh-Hant` and `zh-Hans` it removes the unwanted characters with Regular Expression (be aware that the characters are **not** parentheses and space characters) and swaps both pairs.

```
extension Locale {
    var localizedFullDisplayName : String? {
        if self.identifier.hasPrefix("zh-Han") {
            guard let trimmed = self.localizedString(forIdentifier: self.identifier)?.replacingOccurrences(of: "[（）]", with: "", options: .regularExpression) else { return nil }
            return String(trimmed.suffix(2) + trimmed.prefix(2))
        } else {
            return self.localizedString(forIdentifier: locale.identifier)
        }
    }
}

let locale = Locale(identifier: "zh-Hans")
locale.localizedFullDisplayName
```

Comment: Better than my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. My workaround is just like this. I found that Language setting in iPhone can show full displayname, not just parts, so I ask this question to confirm if there anything I missed.